# Cómo soluciono el error: "Error de inicio del usuario sa"?

Tags: java, jdbc

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Buenas tardes, necesito ayuda para solucionar este error de conexión desde java 8 con sqlserver 2014 mediante jdbc. Realicé todos los pasos según los tutoriales que consulté, incluye a uno de mis profesores de programación a quien le envíe un mail con este screen, quien que me indicó lo siguiente: 
Puede ser que este mal la clave (es 111111), 
que el usuario sa este deshabilitado (no creo),
que el sql server tenga alguna configuracion rara (desconozco).
Desde ya muchas gracias.

Comment: ¿Tienes los drivers correctos para la conexión? Revisa esto: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16877857/java-connection-to-a-sql-server-database-login-failed-for-user-sa

Comment: ¿Dices que tienes la versión 2014 y te intentas conectar con el Driver de SQL Server 2005?  No me extraña que no te funcione, han pasado 9 años, ¿por qué no usas el Driver de la v. 2104? Igualmente confirma que tienes [la librería JDBC adecuada](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/connect/jdbc/download-microsoft-jdbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017) a tu versión de base de datos.

Answer (score 1):

Hola segun veo en la imagen, tienes duplicado el mismo driver:

Microsoft Sql Server 2005

Microsoft Sql Server 2005(1)

Lo primero seria borrar uno de ellos.

Si te das cuenta la conexion que estas intentando abrir con el usuario sd aparece y aparece como conectada. Es decir el usuario sa esta conectado, por lo tanto te da error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al utilizar el wizard debes de pasar los menus, con las opciones tal y como han sido configuradas, es decir algunos campos son obligatorios, y quizas lo que estas intentado hacer no esta previsto y por eso no permite continuar.
No eres el unico que le ha pasado algo similar, a mi tambien me ha pasado, para solucionarlo hago lo siguiente:

Cierro la conexion.
Borro la conexion.
Despues vuelvo a crear la conexion desde el wizard, en mi caso solo uso el wizard para generar Clases Entidad desde base de datos.

Para dar explicacion a lo que esta sucediendo, debes de tener en cuenta que NetBeans utiliza una instancia de GlassFish, es decir realmente se puede decir que estas trabajando con una copia del servidor, no estas trabajando en el servidor real.
Me faltan datos para darte una solucion de lo que te ocurre.
Con que Servidor estas trabajando??
Que es realmente lo que quieres hacer??
Si despliegas haciendo click en la conexion abierta con el usuario sd veras que puedes acceder a las tablas, relizar consultas y ejecutar SQL, tal y como te muestro en la imagen de abajo.
Por favor aclarame que es lo que realmente quieres hacer.
Las conexiones abiertas aparecen con un cuadrado marron.
Las conexiones cerradas con una grieta en medio del cuadrado.
Es decir la tuya esta abierta...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para abrir una conexion cerrada, pulsa con el boton derecho del raton, mira la imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Muchas veces, estos errores se solucionado cerrando NetBeans y abriendolo de nuevo. (Ya que vuelve a crear la instancia del servidor)

Gracias, saludos.